# css: What is the equavalent of -moz-linear-gradient for chrome

Tags: html, css

I have css like `background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #59a1d8, #27247D) repeat scroll 0 0 #0f78c7;` for my buttons which is fine for me in mozilla.
But in chrome browser it is not working, what is the equivalent of this.

Thanks,
nehatha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4096ee), color-stop(100%,#4096ee)); 
// Chrome, Safari4+

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
```

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Nice resource that makes gradients work in most browsers.

Comment: This will not work in chrome10+ according to the site you listed.

Comment: Thanks! Missed that section in the comments. Added the Chrome10+ equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #59a1d8, #27247D) repeat scroll 0 0 #0f78c7;
```

Comment: Yes, I was just skipping the given

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's `-webkit-linear-gradient`