# css not working in chrome and IE

Tags: css

I am new for html and css. Here Is My css code:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #F9F9F9, #F0F0F0) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

this background color effect not working in IE and Chrome How to change this code to work.

Comment: I am not getting you @Paulie_D

Comment: its starting from '-moz'key. that means its supporting for only mozilla family browsers. you have to use commen css command for this or browser specific css with this command

Comment: You use the `-moz-` vendor prefix, and are wondering why it doesn't work in other browsers?

Comment: use this two..
-webkit-linear-gradient 
linear-gradient
http://www.css3files.com/gradient/

Comment: possible duplicate of [css: What is the equavalent of -moz-linear-gradient for chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697218/css-what-is-the-equavalent-of-moz-linear-gradient-for-chrome)

Comment: just type css gradient generators on google...they will give you the code ...finally you have need to add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a gradient only for Mozilla, you need to do it for IE and Chrome separately

Please check this site out as it will do the code for you but, provide comments so you get an idea how each browser responds to each line of code

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Example code

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: @user2869777, check out the link I've provided, it will do it for you whilst giving you all the code you need to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Vendor prefixes are [*no longer needed*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) for gradients.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F9F9F9, #F0F0F0);
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

The `-moz-` prefix is only used by Firefox - so you need to copy the exact line to use in the other browser-familys:

```
background: linear-gradient(center top, #F9F9F9, #F0F0F0) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #F9F9F9, #F0F0F0) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: -o-linear-gradient(center top, #F9F9F9, #F0F0F0) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient. It depends on javascript engine used by browsers.

As it states the doc for crossbrowser:

```
.grad { 
    background-color: #F07575; /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For Chrome and Safari */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For pre-releases of IE 10*/
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
```

}

Comment: `-ms-linear-gradient` has never existed. IE has a tendancy to not jump the gun, and implement features that have been fully standardised, for the most part. Chrome, on the other hand, has at least four different syntaxes for gradients...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol as the doc says it is for pre-releases of IE 10, however you are correct pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

`-moz-linear-gradient` is for Mozilla Browser(Firefox). You should use `webkit-linear-gradient` for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

-moz is a prefix for Mozilla Firefox, please check this site: 
http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
and look through the code and comments:

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
```

Comment: `-ms-linear-gradient` has never existed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, are you sure? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient See the section *History of the syntax*

Comment: IE9 didn't support gradients. IE10 fully supports unprefixed `linear-gradient`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, I agree, but you wrote `-ms-linear-gradient has never existed.`